# Network AAA - concurrent login accounting

Tags: concurrency, session-timeout, aaa-security-protocol

I am looking for a network AAA (authentication, authorization, accounting) protocol that that manage concurrent network resource accessing from one account. An account, say, is logged in by two users concurrently, how can I distribute the session timeout of the account between the two users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are not looking for the specific AAA functionality as used by telecommunications companies, but rather, RADIUS on steroids.   Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to put something like FreeRADIUS on steroids.

I'll assume your particular NAS device (Wifi hub, packet gateway, etc) supports the following RADIUS records.

- Access Request
- Access Accept/Reject
- Accounting Start
- Accounting Stop
- Interim Accounting
- Session Disconnect

When you get a session start, let FreeRADIUS run some sort of script or log that start into the database.  This is your clock start for each user.  Even if the user logs in three times, you'll get start messages.   When they log out for each session, you'll get a session stop.   At a minimum, simply run the database and compute the deltas and apply the accounting rules to that user.   If that user used 10, 20 and 30 minutes in concurrent sessions, you'll get stop records showing 10, 20 and 30 minutes.

This works, but it doesn't go quite far enough.  First, if the sessions are long, you won't know about the time of those sessions until they terminate.   That could be days from now.   This is where the accounting records, particularly the interim accounting records come in.  If your NAS supports it, you can tell it to generate an interim accounting record for a session, say, every 30 minutes.   Thus, if a session lasts 30 minutes or less, you'll get the start and stop records.  If a session lasts 45 minutes however, you'll get:

A start record at time 0
An interim accounting update at time 30
A stop record at time 45

It's not really the AAA you care about -- any RADIUS server likely will do the job -- FreeRADIUS, OpenRADIUS, Microsoft RADIUS server.   It's your NAS device.   If it can't send the records, you can't process them.